# Displaying Ektron submenus in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: menu, widget, submenu, ektron

I'm new to Ektron, and I'm working on a project that has Ektron menus on several pages. The menus are already displaying (someone else made the code for these). This is the code for the menu widget that is being used:

```
@using NEHGS.ResourceEngine

@{

    var widgetModel = Model.UserControl as NEHGS.Models.NehgsSubNavigation; 

    //string clientID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


    ResourceEngine.Register("/widgets/NehgsSubNavigation.css");


}

@Html.Raw(widgetModel.NavigationMarkup)
```

Here is an example of one of the menus this displays:

[image: 1]

In Ektron, Membership is a submenu item which contains 3 submenus, "Guest", "All", and "Information". When I click on "Membership," I need its 3 submenus to display. Being new to Ektron, I have no idea how to access those submenus. If I know how to access them it will be easy enough for me to write code to make them display, but how to I retrieve them from the widgetModel?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to break it to you, but that code is not from Ektron.  My first guess would be that the developer working on it before you has created their own layer on top of Ektron's API.

You also mention you are using MVC?  Ektron does not support MVC yet as it is an ASP.net WebForms application.  I've heard of people creating MVC front ends to Ektron but it usually ends up being more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I agree with Robert in that the code you posted definitely looks like the original developer created their own layer on top of Ektron APIs. I'm afraid you'll have to dig into that model, including the NavigationMarkup property, to figure out what's going on. However, I will disagree with Robert in support for MVC. Ektron does not provide any out-of-the-box aids for MVC, but as a 3-Tier deployment, Ektron does support use of its APIs in that scenario. However, you do lose some forms-only features.